# When does the arithmetic mean of the ratio of two uniformly distributed sequences approach 1?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of numbers uniformly distributed in $(c, d)$ and $b_n$ be another sequence of numbers uniformly distributed in $(x,d), 1 \le c < x < d,$ such that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are independent and

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r = 1}^n\frac{a_r}{b_r} = 1
$$

**Question 1**: What is the expression of $x$ in terms of $c$ and $d$?

**Question 2**: Instead if $b_n$ is uniformly distributed in $(x,y), 1 \le c < x < y < d,$ and satisfies the above limit, what is the minimum value of $y - x$ in terms of $c$ and $d$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? How do you know that $c<x$?

Comment: @Mefitico If both sequences are uniformly distributed in the same interval then the mean of the ratios will be greater than $1$ because of the contributions from the terms where $a_n > b_n$. Hence to reduce the mean to $1$ we need to we need to reduce the width of the interval of $b_n$ from the left side so that smaller values of $b_n$ are eliminated as a result of which the ratio becomes smaller and so does its arithmetic mean.

Comment: Are $a_n$ and $b_n$ independent?

Comment: Also in what sense does the avg converge to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

**Q1** Let $A$ and $B$ be random variables uniformly distributed as per the post.

We require $E(\frac{A}{B})=1$ and therefore $E(A)E(\frac{1}{B})=1$.

$E(A)$ is just $\frac{c+d}{2}$ and $E(\frac{1}{B})=\int_{x}^{d} \frac{1}{d-x}\frac{1}{t} dt=\frac{1}{d-x}(\text {ln} d-\text {ln} x)$.

Therefore

$$\frac{c+d}{2}\frac{\text {ln} (d)-\text {ln}(x)}{d-x}=1.$$

**Q2** To minimise $y-x$ one would then need to make $x=c$. Then
$$\frac{c+d}{2}\frac{\text {ln} (y)-\text {ln}(c)}{y-c}=1.$$

Comment: Can you put the proof/ derivation pls because I

Comment: For a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$, $E(\frac{1}{X})$ is the integral of $\frac{1}{b-a}\frac{1}{x}$ over the interval.

Comment: Is that the derivation you wanted?

Comment: I think the answer to Q1 is correct. But for Q2, I can construct many examples of solutions with $x > c, y < d$. The assumption $x = c$ for minima is not valid.

Comment: Yes, but are your $y-x$s smaller than the one above? The shape of the ln$x$ graph determines which interval will have minimal length.